# strace or procmon equivalent for java

Tags: java, linux, windows

When I run a C++ program, and it says "unable to open file" but does not say what the filename is, I normally use strace (Linux) or procmon(Windows) to find out which file it is trying to open and where it is looking for it.

I can't do that with java programs because all this is controlled from the java vm.  Some of the jars/classes I deal with have configuration files which are optional.  Sometimes, it would be nice to know what these configuration files (like .css files for javafx programs) are called, especially when no errors are reported.

If I don't have access to the sources, for instance, when I am given a .jar or .class file, is there an equivalent of strace  (Linux) or procmon (windows) for java or is it some combination of debug options that gets the java VM to list out what files it is trying to open or where it is looking for the files?

Comment: What’s wrong with strace? A java process is just another process and it opens files using kernel calls like any other process.

Comment: I completely agree - I think there are even techniques to enable strace / dtrace to understand what is happening on a byte code level. You might want to search the se-radio.net podcast - there is one episode on dtrace that also talks about using that for debugging Java applications.

Comment: Maybe I'm running strace incorrectly but I can't even see the jar or class files being loaded: just a bunch of .so files and that's it.

Comment: I'll have a look at dtrace - haven't used that tool before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around a lot, it looks like it is back to strace.

```
strace -f java xxx | egrep openat 1> files.log 2>&1
```

Then look at the files.log.  What I didn't appreciate was that java launches the executable as a different process.  strace -f traces the forked processes as well.

openat is the call for opening files.  There are lots opens on class, jar and .so files.  Once those have been taken out, what you are left with is all the other files.

Answer (score 1):

try lsof in linux, which can list files open by the process 
if it what you looking for ,
or you can always attach JVM debugger. 
or if you know more about java class loader, you can use it to find out .

Comment: Tried lsof - it only lists open files.  I'm looking for what file it is trying to open but cannot find.  I'll have a play with jdb and see what it can tell me.

Comment: if it is not a big jar , you can open the files inside and search for strings like file names  , it may help you to locate it